# Text file Issues (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fstream, iostream

I'm trying to make it so the program prompts the user for the name of the file, then prompt them for what word they'd like to be removed.
Is there a way to do so without making any functions outside from main?
(Thanks in advance!)
Here's my code so far:

```
ofstream outFile;
string in;
char in2[800];
char fileName = ' ';
while (in != "XXXX") {
    cout << "What do you want to name the file? Enter a name or enter XXXX to quit.\n";
    cin >> in;

    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        fileName += in[i];
    }
    outFile.open(in + ".txt");
    if (outFile.fail())
    {
        outFile << "Can't do it.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "What do you want in it?\n";
        cin >> in2;
        cin.getline(in2, sizeof(in2));
        outFile << in2;
    }
    outFile.close();
    ifstream reader;
    string oneLine;
    reader.open(in + ".txt");
    if (reader.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not read file.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        reader.clear();
        reader.seekg(60L, ios::beg);
        getline(reader, oneLine);
        cout << "Is there something you'd like to remove from " << in << ".txt?\n";
        cin >> in2;
        ofstream write("tmp.txt");
        while (getline(reader, oneLine)) {
            if (oneLine != in2)
                write << oneLine << endl;
        }
        reader.close();
        write.close();
        remove(fileName + ".txt");
        rename("tmp.txt", fileName + ".txt");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apologies. Misread. `in2` was the `char` array, not `in`.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not want functions? They are almost always more desirable from a division of responsibilities and code readability standpoint.

Comment: Work through your code line by line and understand what every statement does. fileName += in[i] doesn't do what you probably except it to.

Comment: @Hristijan Gjorshevski neither does his out file << "cant do it"; in that specific code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while (in != "XXXX") {
>     cout << "What do you want to name the file? Enter a name or enter XXXX to quit.\n";
>     ...
> }
> ```

If you enter `XXXX` the loop won't quit. It will try to process the rest of the code.

`char fileName = ' ';` declares a single character. You want an array of characters. Better yet, declare it as `std::string fileName;`

`remove(fileName + ".txt");` won't compile because `remove` is a C function. C doesn't support classes and it doesn't know what to do with classes such as `std::string`. You want to supply a C-string, you can do that with `fileName.c_str()` Below are a few suggestions:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outFile;
    string fileName;
    string text;
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "What do you want to name the file?\n";
        cout << "Enter a name or enter 999 to quit.\n";
        cin >> fileName;

        if(fileName == "999")
            break;

        fileName += ".txt";
        outFile.open(fileName);
        if(outFile.fail())
        {
            cout << "Can't do it.";
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            for(;;)
            {
                cout << "What do you want in it?\n";
                cout << "Enter a name or enter 999 to stop.\n";
                cin >> text;
                if(text == "999")
                    break;
                outFile << text << endl;
            }
        }
        outFile.close();

        ifstream reader;
        reader.open(fileName);
        if(reader.fail())
        {
            cout << "Could not read file.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Is there something you'd like to remove from " << fileName << "?\n";
            cin >> text;

            string oneLine;
            ofstream write("tmp.txt");
            while(getline(reader, oneLine)) 
            {
                if(oneLine != text)
                    write << oneLine << endl;
            }
            reader.close();
            write.close();

            remove(fileName.c_str());
            rename("tmp.txt", fileName.c_str());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmak! This works exactly the way I wanted it to.